# Maximum file size for HTML that browser can open

Tags: html, browser

What's the maximum file size for an HTML that browser e.g. Opera can open? Without images, just html, not for indexing by search engine and only for PERSONAL opening at local machine

Comment: I would assume available memory is the only limit. If I was a user of your website though, the fact you are asking this question would scare me. What are you trying to display that is so huge?

Comment: I upvoted because it's an interesting question I don't have or found an answer right now, but in practice, for sure the acceptablelimit is the use case limit. All major kind of targeted users must have enough memory to run your webapp ;-)

Comment: It's no for users — it's for my personal and local using only

Comment: I agree. I would like to know the answer to this question. As a web developer, this is something I should know. Although I hope that I would never build such a page that comes even close to the limit!